# React Native: EAS IOS local development build not using my credentials.json, but stuck using a previous AdHoc profile that is deleted

Tags: ios, react-native, eas

My EAS IOS development build is failing, because EAS tries to use the wrong provisioning profile.
I created a new device and certificate mobile provisioning profile on the Apple development sites, set the profile in my Gymfile, and credentials.json, using KeyChain Access.
I used "was credentials" to upload the credential files to EAS.

but when I run
`was build --platform ios --profile development --local`
Expo always logs into the Apple Dev portal and either creates a new provisioning profile or uses the last one it created which doesn't match what I have set up in credentials.json or the Gymfile.

```
{
  "ios": {
    "distributionCertificate": {
      "path": "credentials/iOS/xxxx.p12",
      "password": "xxxx"
    },
    "provisioningProfilePath": "credentials/iOS/xxxx.mobileprovision"
  }
}
```

Gymfile

```
suppress_xcode_output(false)
clean(false)
disable_xcpretty(false)
output_directory("./app_builds")
sdk("iphoneos")
export_method("development")
xcargs("CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Manual")
export_options( provisioningProfiles: {   "com.xxxx.yyyy" => "com.xxx.yyyy zzzz" },signingStyle: "manual")
codesigning_identity("Apple Development: qqqqq")
```

eas.json

```
  "cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.38.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "ios": {"image": "latest"},
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```

Where the 'xxxx' etc are my redacted credentials names

Answer (score 3):

To use your local credentials.json, you need to specify the credential source is local as described here:
https://docs.expo.dev/app-signing/local-credentials/#setting-a-credentials-source

eas.json

```
"cli": {
    "version": ">= 0.38.1"
  },
  "build": {
    "development": {
      "ios": {"image": "latest"},
      "developmentClient": true,
      "distribution": "internal",
      "credentialsSource": "local"
    },
    "preview": {
      "distribution": "internal",
      "developmentClient": true,
      "android": {
        "buildType": "apk"
      }
    },
    "production": {}
  },
  "submit": {
    "production": {}
  }
}
```